# System.StackOverflowException when reading in a file c#

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to read a file in to my wpf program but the System.StackOverflowException is occuring! Any help would be amazing, thank you!!

My Code:

```
 private void BestSellerListtxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] TopFictionArray = File.ReadAllLines("TopFiction.txt");
        string[] TopNonFictionArray = File.ReadAllLines("TopNonFiction.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < TopFictionArray.Length; i++)
        {
            BestSellerListtxt.Text = TopFictionArray[i];
        }

        BestSellerListtxt.Text = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < TopNonFictionArray.Length; i++)
        {
            BestSellerListtxt.Text = TopNonFictionArray[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're assigning to `BestSellerListtxt.Text` (multiple times), which presumably triggers `BestSellerListtxt_TextChanged` ?

Comment: Thank you! How would i print out the contents of the array?

Comment: I'm not a WPF expert, but I'd guess "add them into a ListView"? I can't opine on UI design - they don't let me play with crayons much, I'm more of a console/server person :)

Comment: What is your use case of filling in the text field when its content changes? Instead of `BestSellerListtxt_TextChanged` can you have a `Load` button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and with the help of string.Join(Delimeter, array) you can concat arrays elements without using loops and easily can print

```
BestSellerListtxt.Text = string.Join("," , TopFictionArray);

BestSellerListtxt_TextChanged = strin.join("," , TopNonFictionArray);
```